# Send Links with POST Data via E-Mail

Tags: php, email, post, hyperlink

I want to know how to send a Link in an E-Mail which Contains `$_POST` data. It's for a E-Mail reset function in php. I don't really want to send an E-Mail with a Link like

```
    http://example.reset.com/reset.php?token=5e51b695b8260632e55cad464039c2b4d7ec2cbca0331b881fabc4ada71cffac3808aa105ec5e9a9b693768774ddb6c3160359f9195c2e442c7c7a82ed849033
```

So is it possible to realize this?

I already check if the token is in the database and if the `$exp_date_time` info is not to old. The User just has 30 Minutes to change his Password, after getting the Mail. If one of these Steps doesn't work the Person who tried to connect to `reset.php` will be redirected to the `index.php`.

Now I don't want to have a Bot who accidentally get a positive Response to this.

For Information the token Length is 128 and was generated by a generated random password with a modified sha512 hash.

How can I make this even more Secure?

Cheers

Sven

Additional Information:

My Database:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `email` (
  `kasuser` varchar(12) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `be_mail` varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `ba_mail` varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `exp_date` varchar(19) NOT NULL DEFAULT '2000-01-01 01:01:01',
  `token` varchar(200) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`kasuser`),
  UNIQUE KEY `be_mail` (`be_mail`),
  UNIQUE KEY `ba_mail` (`ba_mail`)
)
```

to get a link like the one above, you need to fill in an Form, which checks, if the backup_mail (ba_mail) is in the database and bound to be_mail, which you also have to send with the form. Then a date is generated with +30min and a token is generated by a password generator which hashes the Password and saves the end product to the Database. Then a E-Mail is send to the ba_mail with a link above.

I also wonder if it's possible to generate a "link" with a hidden form, which sends the token to the php as $_POST which requires it. But I doubt, that this will work in E-Mail Clients and there are some people which just see plain text. So I have at least send to them the token as GET or?

Comment: Do you want to add a special question before changing the password ? As : "What is your favorite animal name ?"

Comment: The more secret it needs the more secrets could be forgotten. So no not really.

Comment: The example you posted is a `$_GET`, you cannot generate `$_POST` data from a url.

Answer (score 0):

You could generate the token and store it with an email in your db, than pass both of those in your email link.

reset.php?token=5e51b_etc&email=test%40example.com

```
$email = urldecode($_GET['email']);
$token = $_GET['token'];
```

You would craft a query to check that the token and email match in your db.

**edit:** you would also check that the time of access is less than your `$exp_date_time`.

**edit 2:**
I just noticed 'I don't really want to send an E-Mail with a Link like'.
You can avoid what the link looks like in the email `Password Reset.
Than use the get data to process the request and redirect with either a valid attempt/change password, or the parameters are wrong or request is too old. I wouldn't worry about the url in the scenario. It's not going to be something the visitor is going to return to unless they are sent another email reset.